# Performance issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle10g, toad

The requirement here is to present user with Forecast details for particular PLANT or Part Number. The Forecast Details are coming from few source tables and UNIONed by one VIEW. A materialized view (MV) is created on this view for faster data access. After taking record count on this MV, its coming as 500K+.

We have a DOTNET application web page, where user selects the Plant or enters the parts and requests data for these filter from the above MV. The part Filter is working fine, but the Plant Filter is almost taking 20 mins to pull data for certain Plant.

As per further analysis I found that few of the Plants have more than 50K rows in the MV.  Is retrieving 50K+ records is issue??

Following is the query, when Executed runs quickly, but at the same time when executed using Execute Script option, takes 5-6 minutes to return rows.

```
SELECT  /*+ hint first_rows(1000) */
PLANT,MATERIAL_NBR,SOLD_TO_CODE,SHIP_TO_CODE,SHIP_TO_NAME,SHIP_TO_PLANT,SHIP_TO_LABEL_FMT,ORD_QTY,ALLOC_QTY,
due_date, PRIME_CNTR,PRIME_UOI,SEC_CNTR,BASE_UOM,ORDER_TYPE,SHIP_POINT,REC_TYPE  
FROM GTCPDBA.VW_FORECAST_REQMNTS_DET 
Where PLANT ='FR10';
```

Please suggest some inputs.

Comment: Would there be any latency issues with accessing the path that the script is located? I don't see why executing it as a script or just querying would make a difference really

Comment: In toad there is an option called Execute Script. I meant that

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are running the same queries in Execute and Execute script? Perhaps you are querying the view instead of the materialized view in one case (the suffix VW_ in your query seems to suggest that)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use first_rows optimizer hint? This one should be used when your application supports producer-consumer design pattern. i.e. you have background thread which fetches data from DB and displays them on the "thick" client's screen.

Something like that is hardly achievable on  3-TIER web application.